# Angular 2 binding within binding. Interpolation within event

Tags: events, binding, angular, interpolation

Trying to do the following and getting **"Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected"** error.

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#item of items">
    <a href='' (click)="foo('{{item.name}}')">{{item.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't use `{{}}`(interpolation) inside any event handler code (on a view), do pass expression directly which will get evaluated against `Component` context(`this`), like over here you're trying to pass `item.name` to `foo` function. So removing `{{}}` parenthesis would do the trick.

```
<a href="" (click)="foo(item.name)">
  {{item.name}}
</a>
```