# How can I get dynamic data from (click) event on Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Here is my component where i am loading video id in `i` tag on click event. I want to access this id from `video.component.ts` file. And want to load new video dynamically. I can't figure out how to load it.

```
<li *ngFor="let video of chapter.video" 
    class="list-group-item hoverEffect">
     <a 
     routerLink="video/{{ video.ytd }}" class="linkHover">
     <i 
     (click)="loadVideo({{ video.id }})" class="fa fa-play-circle float-right"></i>
                      {{ video.title }}
     </a>
</li>
```

this is function in my `ts` file

```
  loadVideo(video: any){
    this.player = video;
  }
```

Comment: Follow this link you will get clear Idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659854/angular-2-binding-within-binding-interpolation-within-event

Answer (score 1):

Remove the interpolation:

```html
<li *ngFor="let video of chapter.video" 
    class="list-group-item hoverEffect">
     <a 
     routerLink="video/{{ video.ytd }}" class="linkHover">
     <i 
     ̶(̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶)̶=̶"̶l̶o̶a̶d̶V̶i̶d̶e̶o̶(̶{̶{̶ ̶v̶i̶d̶e̶o̶.̶i̶d̶ ̶}̶}̶)̶"̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶=̶"̶f̶a̶ ̶f̶a̶-̶p̶l̶a̶y̶-̶c̶i̶r̶c̶l̶e̶ ̶f̶l̶o̶a̶t̶-̶r̶i̶g̶h̶t̶"̶
     (click)="loadVideo(video.id)" class="fa fa-play-circle float-right">
     </i>
                      {{ video.title }}
     </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I'm stealing that idea! :-)